How to scan hidden Chrome download bubble
I would really appreciate the advice about how to scan the Chrome download bubble with the list of recently downloaded documents.
I need to check if the right document was downloaded and in some test cases I need to open it in Downloads folder, in some test cases I need to find first or second element of the list.
Can somebody please give me some hint or advice how to solve it. This is the Downloads bubble which I am trying to scan and steer
I tried standard UIA Scanning, but by this method I am able to scan only the button  for Downloads on Chrome toolbar, but this doesn't allow me to open and scan the "bubble" with downloaded documents.
As this is not part of HTML code of the page pausing JavaScript doesn't work. https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/how-to-pause-javascript-and-inspect-an-element-that-quickly-disappears/
Shortcut Ctrl+J to open all downloaded documents is not the way for me, because, I suppose for security reasons, Tosca is not able to scan web page chrome://downloads/ on my local machine neither on our virtual machines.
